# How can make the html code be formatted in one line?

Tags: language-agnostic

How can make the HTML code be formatted in one line, during run time.
thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you referring to the way in which it is displayed when you view the source?

Comment: yest, when the web page is running. 
not during written the code.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: What web-server are you using, and is your html in one of html,htm,xhtml,xml files or is it in something else like a php,jsp,asp,etc?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it manually with this:

[Compress HTML](http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php)

Or you could look into integrating this tool into your development process:

[HTML Compresssor](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/)

Answer (score 2):

You can compress HTML file using any compressor avaible. Here are few:

[HTML Minifier](http://minifycode.com/html-minifier/)

[HTML Compressor](https://htmlcompressor.com/)

[Minfiy HTML](https://www.smteto.com/html-minify-online-tool/)